# SQL first and last timestamp per day per user

Tags: sql, sql-server, window-functions

I have a table with a userId and timestamp. For every user, I'd like to get for each day the first and the last timestamp. I'm using SQL Server.
How it looks like:

```
|User|         Date        |
----------------------------
| 1  | 2015-01-08 07:31:40 |
| 1  | 2015-01-08 18:35:40 |
| 1  | 2015-01-08 22:31:40 |
| 1  | 2015-01-09 05:35:40 | 
| 1  | 2015-01-09 06:31:40 |
| 1  | 2015-01-09 07:35:40 | 
| 1  | 2015-01-09 12:38:40 | 
| 1  | 2015-01-09 23:38:40 |    
| 2  | 2015-01-08 05:55:40 |
| 2  | 2015-01-08 10:48:40 |
| 2  | 2015-01-08 15:38:40 |
| 2  | 2015-01-08 21:50:40 |
| 2  | 2015-01-09 10:38:40 |
| 2  | 2015-01-09 14:33:40 |
| 2  | 2015-01-09 15:38:40 |
| 2  | 2015-01-09 17:38:40 |
| 2  | 2015-01-09 19:55:40 |
```

The output I need:

```
|User|         Date        |
----------------------------
| 1  | 2015-01-08 07:31:40 |
| 1  | 2015-01-08 22:31:40 |
| 1  | 2015-01-09 05:35:40 |
| 1  | 2015-01-09 23:38:40 |
| 2  | 2015-01-08 05:55:40 |
| 2  | 2015-01-08 21:50:40 |
| 2  | 2015-01-09 10:38:40 |
| 2  | 2015-01-09 19:55:40 |
```

So far it works for only one username:

```
SELECT 
    User, 
    Date, 
    min(Date) OVER(PARTITION BY Datepart(dy,Date)) as first, 
    max(Date) OVER(PARTITION BY Datepart(dy,Date)) as last
FROM 
    Tablename
WHERE 
    User = UserId
```

Comment: Check out GROUP BY!

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: show what you have done so far... Go through [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

Group by user and date columns. Date column has to be trimmed for its time part, like this:

```
SELECT MAX([Date]), MIN([Date]) FROM [TableName] GROUP BY [User], CONVERT(DATE, [Date])
```

Syntax is valid for SQL Server, but approach should be DBMS agnostic

Comment: It will give first value and last value of the groupby, It won't work. please look this again.

Comment: yes, but he wants the first - MIN and the last - MAX value per day and user (used in GROUP BY). i think it meets the criteria he requires.

Comment: It won't meet the query because of partition on basis of date.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
    User, 
    Date, 
    min(Date) OVER(PARTITION BY Datepart(dy,Date)) as first, 
    max(Date) OVER(PARTITION BY Datepart(dy,Date)) as last
FROM 
    Tablename
GROUP BY
    Userid
```

This `Group-By` statement may exalt your code, Add your valuable feedback on Answer's comment section.